# Как идентифицировать юзера, залогинившегося с Facebook?

Tags: facebook-widgets, php, facebook, javascript, facebook-api

Добрый день.

Кто-то в курсе, каким образом можно идентифицировать юзера, что залогинился у нас на сайте через facebook api?

Имею на сайте метод FB.login из facebook'овского api JS SDK.

Что уже сделано:
юзер заходит на сайт, жмет на кнопку 'Войти через facebook', если это самый первый раз - он подтверждает права, логинится и передает нам кое-какие стандартные данные о себе, со своей стороны проверяем, есть ли у нас в базе юзер с таким айди, если нету - записываем его к нам и все данные о нем.
Юзер заходит во второй раз, жмет ту же кнопку, фейсбук его сразу авторизирует. Мы же на своей стороне проверяем, оказывается, что такой уже есть - не записываем снова его данные в базу.

Чего хочу добиться:
когда юзер авторизируется, его перебрасывает в свой профиль на нашем сайте, и я никак не могу понять, каким образом идентифицировать юзера? Т.е. если, допустим, взять просто id юзера в фейсбуке, разве тогда кто-либо другой не сможет просто подставить id того юзера и 'войти' в его профиль? Какими техниками обычно пользуются в таком случае вообще? Или другими словами - как войдя через fb.login идентифицировать юзера и совместить с профилем этого юзера на нашем сайте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, на stackoverflow сказали, что сверять по fb id - достаточно.

Comment: По идее ID никак не подставить левое.

Comment: вот и славно :)

Comment: + еще FB возвращает верифицированное фейсбуком мыло. Т.е тоже левое не подставишь.